# Have there been any right-hemisphere-dominant split-brain-patients?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, lateralization

Do any case studies of right-hemisphere dominant individuals who have undergone a severance of the corpus callosum exist? Thanks.